# similarities and differences between ACO and PSO and Genetic algorithms

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm, particle-swarm, ant-colony

Hi guys I want to know what is the main similarities and differences between **Ant colony optimization algorithm** and **Particle swarm optimization** and **Genetic algorithm**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Particle swarm optimization is a population based stochastic optimization. It  is  motivated  by  the  behavior  of  flocks  of  birds  or swarms  of  fishes  to  search  for  a  good  food  place. the coordinates in the search space that are associated with the best solution is tracked by each particle. It is random.

While Ant colony optimization algorithm is a probabilistic technique for solving non-deterministic problems. The requirement for designing an Ant colony optimization algorithm is to have a constructive method such as used by an ant to create different solutions through a sequence of decisions.

Comment: You're welcome please upvote it if it's helpful.

Comment: yes it was helpful .thanks again>